# What is this JSON date in this JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have some `JSON` to analyze

This is the snippet of it that is necessary for this question.

```
"UpdatedDate":"\/Date(1311377875937)\/"
```

I don't know that number is, but updated date is the date the item was last updated

Also, whatever it is, how would i be able to find out if it was updated 20 seconds ago or less?

Comment: its a function that you can execute and data stored in `jsonobj.UpdatedDate`. comparing new Date() to this will give to time difference

Comment: Try this: `var date= eval("new "+obj.UpdatedDate.replace(/\//g, ""))`. then you can check `new Date().getSeconds()-date.getSeconds() > 20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number is a DateTime, in milliseconds, since 1970. If you divide the 2 DateTimes you have by 1000 and subtract them you should get the difference in seconds.

```
var secondsDifference = (new Date() - UpdateDate)/1000;
```

Comment: You want `new Date() - UpdateDate`

Comment: Clovola had the order backwards, you'd want to do `new Date() - UpdatedDate`. But if you ever do encounter a negative value, you were sent a date in the future (or the client's time is off).

Answer (score 0):

Some JSON encoders (I'm not sure which ones, or maybe this is done *manually*), save dates in this format.  The number is a *unix timestamp*, representing the date this was updated.

To get a `Date` object from this, you'll need to parse out the numbers from the string and pass it to the `Date()` constructor.

```
var dateStr = obj.UpdatedDate;
var dateInfo = dateStr.match(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//);

var update = new Date(parseInt(dateInfo[1], 10));
```

To see if this is within 20 seconds, you can just subtract this date object from a new one (which represents) the current time.

```
var diff = Date.now() - update;  // This will be a value in milliseconds
var diffSec = diff/1000;  // Now it's in seconds
```